# How can I toggle on and off 2 materials for a single mesh?

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image]

I am creating a hair asset for a video game to be used within a character creator menu.
We want to have a second hair material which can be toggled on and off. Depending on which hair mesh this can be like highlights in the hair or partly gray hair, ect.

I have very little experience with material nodes so let me explain the purpose of what I am doing first.

We have an early version of this working in Unreal Engine 4 already with the experimenting we have done but for the most part is figured out. In the UV map I put all of the "second type" parts to the right and the rest of the hair on the left. My programmer then uses an image with solid red and green to key out the two parts.

The problem is Unreal uses completely different terms from Blender so I can't preview anything before sending assets to him.

I have followed this tutorial but the problem with it is this guy can't toggle on or off a full solid color for the monkey, it's always two colors.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms89wP8m4ZU

Thank you to anyone who can help me with this <3

Comment: Please show your current work as wisely chosen and annotated Blender screen captures or better .   For nodes ... look at a [mix shader] which can mix two different shaders .. in the proportions you choose. Examples ..100% of Material A ... 100% of Material B .... or 50% of both ... or any other reasonable combination.  Without your work showing .. I find your question vague.  Someone else may find it clear. Please Search Mix Shader Node.

Comment: Shader Nodes also have the equivalent of functions taking parameter inputs for reuse, minimizing duplication.

Comment: Hi thank you for commenting! Mix Shader does look like it's on the right path but I'm still not sure how to approach this. I posted pictures of it [here](https://imgur.com/a/GNLqH7s) with annotations

Comment: Blender Materials use texture coordinates.  Texture Coordinates can be transformed mathematically.   You may also consider searching for topic ... using one texture map and changing coordinates.  You can use numeric values to select a portion of a texture.  I am having difficulty understanding what you wrote above.

Comment: Oh I actually figured out how to do it! Sorry if I wasn't descriptive enough, I just don't know enough of the Blender terms yet to describe what I was trying to do. Here's the end result of what I wanted [https://imgur.com/a/5bm2YpH](https://imgur.com/a/5bm2YpH). Basically I wanted to have the rainbow and white be separate materials but tell Blender where to put them. With your Shader suggestion I looked up how they work and made that black and white material for the Fac input. It's going to look nicer by the time I'm done but this is the basic thing I currently needed :)